# Database vs application security design

Tags: php, sql-server, database

So I'm currently in the process of creating a small public website (where users can, for example, log in and change personal information), but I am wondering how the database security is actually designed for that type of thing, so I have several questions.

When an internet user accesses a page like stackoverflow, for example (without logging in on the site), which database user or role is he logged on in order to be able to see all the posted questions? Then, when the user logs in with his account, does his role in the database change (since he has more rights)?

If I setup my database to have a "Users" as well as a "Permissions" table, I can make sure that a user can only have access to his own data, at least application side. But how do I make sure the data is still protected database side since I suppose every public user has the same "database login" or "role"?

I know my question is probably a bit unclear, but don't hesitate to ask me for clarifications. I didn't really know where to begin.

Thanks.

P.S.: I'm currently using SQL Server

Comment: Not the right place for a question like this. But I think sites like these are likely to use replication, and switch back and forth between master/slave connections depending on read-/write operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question.

Generally, your website will run under some user account, lets call this 'IWEB', this user account will be the same for everyone that hits your website, regardless of whether the user is logged into your website or not.

IWEB will have permissions to read data from a database. That's how the anonymous users work.

In your database you will have a user table, possibly a permissions table. IWEB will be given database permissions to create new users, update users. It possibly will be prevented from deleting users.

Your application will (though IWEB) use these tables to control who has access to your application and who can update what. A bug (e.g. SQL Injection) in your application could allow a malicious user to create admin accounts, change other users passwords etc...

In certain scenarios e.g. using Windows Authentication, you can pass through the user logged into your site, translate that into a database user and given them permissions. However you are unlikely to do that for a public facing website.

You could possibly do something where the tables are not directly accessed, but are controlled through stored procedures, denying access to the underlying tables. One of the parameters is the currently logged in user, that could then control access at the database layer (prevent a user updating another users profile). Unless of course your application has a bug that could allow an attacker to change their currently logged in user.

It all depends on your security requirements. In the main though, you will control access at your application.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, it was really useful.

I guess my problem lies in understanding the difference between SQL Server users (the ones who connect to the database with a password like sa or windows authentication) and login-less database users (like the default user "guest"). If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I create a an SQL user without login called "IWEB", and that wouldn't cause any security issue since users without logins cannot connect directly connect to the database if they don't use the application?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's it. You create a SQL Server login on the server 'IWEB' (either windows or sql), you create a user in a database which maps to that login, give that user permissions on the tables that the application needs. Your application connects to the database as that user. Your website users have their own accounts (or not) and you control what they can do with the application. IWEB has the permissions to perform those actions in the DB. If you have a security hole in your application, that can allow an attacker to do things you didn't intent.

Comment: Thank you. I have another subquestion. When a public user arrives on the website, I log him trough Windows Authentication (in php i looks like this:    $conn = sqlsrv_connect("localhost", array("Database"=>"DatabaseName"));)    Does Windows Authentication uses the credentials of the user, or the credentials of the machine on which SQL server is running?

Comment: I'm not a PHP person so i'm not sure, but I'd expect it's the user which your webserver process is running under.

Answer (score 1):

Database role doesn't change, but functions do. Users are authorized from the back end code, not from directly database. If you are trying to create logins for every single user for your database, that would not be a good aproach since there could be thousands or milions of users which somehow can have direct access to your database with some permissions.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with having an Anonymous user in the Users table, having the lowest privileges in the Permissions table?

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: When a user first lands on a web page they have no 'role'. Your scripting will decide what the users can and cannot see.

For example you have a post that only certain user can see. That post will be hidden by default. Your script should then run a test to see if the user is currently logged in and if that user is in the permission group to view that post. If they are, then show the post.

Your database should not be accessible either way.